# Why "Not enough space"-error on internet-browser launch? tmpdf?

Tags: debian, storage, tmpfs

For several applications I am getting a "Not enough space"-error which I wish to solve.

Examble (My debian is in German):

```
$ chromium
[2595:2595:0805/143635.823734:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)]
Failed to create /home/jk/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: 
Auf dem Gerät ist kein Speicherplatz mehr verfügbar (28)
[2595:2595:0805/143635.823938:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1410)] 
Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. 
This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser
processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. 
Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
$
```

I ran `htop` and I can't find anything with `chrom` using th `F3` function.

Also, I have this free space:

```
# df -T
Filesystem     Type      1K-blocks    Used Available  Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   4060868        0   4060868    0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       814432     9488    804944    2% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4      34352812  6819976  25758092   21% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      4072144    30804   4041340    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120        4      5116    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      4072144        0   4072144    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5      ext4      71731064 20562300  47539148   31% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs       814428        4    814424    1% /run/user/111
tmpfs          tmpfs       814428       16    814412    1% /run/user/1000
#
```

From another question I also checked this output:

```
# lsof | fgrep deleted
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/111/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
pulseaudi 1235                    jk    6u      REG                0,5 67108864      20258 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
alsa-sink 1235 1296               jk    6u      REG                0,5 67108864      20258 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
alsa-sour 1235 1297               jk    6u      REG                0,5 67108864      20258 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   15u      REG                8,1     1917    1962258 /tmp/vteFUZ45Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   16u      REG                8,1     1312    1962259 /tmp/vteLEY45Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   23u      REG                8,1     2042    1962279 /tmp/vteQW8B6Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   24u      REG                8,1      624    1962282 /tmp/vteNS8B6Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   28u      REG                8,1     1944    1962283 /tmp/vteD5BA6Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   29u      REG                8,1      384    1962285 /tmp/vteKXBA6Z (deleted)
lxtermina 1303                    jk   30u      REG                8,1     2864    1962286 /tmp/vteLLCA6Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   15u      REG                8,1     1917    1962258 /tmp/vteFUZ45Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   16u      REG                8,1     1312    1962259 /tmp/vteLEY45Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   23u      REG                8,1     2042    1962279 /tmp/vteQW8B6Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   24u      REG                8,1      624    1962282 /tmp/vteNS8B6Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   28u      REG                8,1     1944    1962283 /tmp/vteD5BA6Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   29u      REG                8,1      384    1962285 /tmp/vteKXBA6Z (deleted)
gmain     1303 1306               jk   30u      REG                8,1     2864    1962286 /tmp/vteLLCA6Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   15u      REG                8,1     1917    1962258 /tmp/vteFUZ45Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   16u      REG                8,1     1312    1962259 /tmp/vteLEY45Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   23u      REG                8,1     2042    1962279 /tmp/vteQW8B6Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   24u      REG                8,1      624    1962282 /tmp/vteNS8B6Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   28u      REG                8,1     1944    1962283 /tmp/vteD5BA6Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   29u      REG                8,1      384    1962285 /tmp/vteKXBA6Z (deleted)
gdbus     1303 1309               jk   30u      REG                8,1     2864    1962286 /tmp/vteLLCA6Z (deleted)
firefox-e 1901                    jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Gecko_IOT 1901 1904               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Timer     1901 1905               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Link\x20M 1901 1906               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Socket    1901 1907               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
JS\x20Wat 1901 1908               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
JS\x20Hel 1901 1909               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
JS\x20Hel 1901 1910               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
AudioIPC  1901 1911               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
AudioIPC  1901 1912               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Hang\x20M 1901 1914               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
gmain     1901 1915               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
gdbus     1901 1916               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Cache2    1901 1919               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Cookie    1901 1920               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
GMPThread 1901 1922               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Softwar~c 1901 1923               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Composito 1901 1924               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
VRListene 1901 1925               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ImgDecode 1901 1926               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ImageIO   1901 1927               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
IPDL\x20B 1901 1932               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
HTML5\x20 1901 1933               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DOM\x20Wo 1901 1936               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
firefox-e 1901 1937               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
firefox-e 1901 1938               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ImageBr~g 1901 1940               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
FS\x20Bro 1901 1941               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ProcessHa 1901 1942               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
LoadRoots 1901 1958               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DataStora 1901 1959               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DataStora 1901 1960               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
SysProxyS 1901 1961               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
dconf\x20 1901 1962               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ProxyReso 1901 1963               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DataStora 1901 1964               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
URL\x20Cl 1901 1965               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Classif~  1901 1967               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
SaveScrip 1901 1968               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
Cache\x20 1901 1969               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DataStora 1901 1970               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
mozStorag 1901 1971               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
QuotaMana 1901 1986               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
ImgDecode 1901 1987               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
FS\x20Bro 1901 1994               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
mozStorag 1901 2015               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
threaded- 1901 2062               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
FS\x20Bro 1901 2120               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DOM\x20Wo 1901 2348               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
FS\x20Bro 1901 2426               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DNS\x20Re 1901 2444               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
DNS\x20Re 1901 2460               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
StreamTra 1901 2476               jk  122r      REG                8,1  1222721    1962287 /tmp/tmp-3yq.xpi (deleted)
# df
```

`/run/user/111/gvfs` and `/run/user/1000/gvfs` is where two partitions of one of my android devices get mounted.

I am stuck, what can I do?

As user telcoM noted, the output of `df -i` is absolutely relevant:

```
$ df -i
Dateisystem     Inodes IBenutzt   IFrei IUse% Eingehängt auf
udev           1015217      460 1014757    1% /dev
tmpfs          1018036      686 1017350    1% /run
/dev/sda1      2199344   176230 2023114    9% /
tmpfs          1018036       36 1018000    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1018036        4 1018032    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1018036       15 1018021    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5        17664    17664       0  100% /home
tmpfs          1018036       15 1018021    1% /run/user/111
tmpfs          1018036       22 1018014    1% /run/user/1000
$
```

It shows I have no free inodes left! I really don't know how I managed to create only `17664` inodes for the `/home/` partition which is almost 69GiB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/home` filesystem uses the `ext4` filesystem type, which cannot dynamically create new inodes on demand. So if you have a large number of small files, you may have run out of inodes even though there are still a lot of free space left. Please run `df -i` to see the inode allocation status.

The problem is, at `ext4` filesystem creation time, you can choose "inode density", i.e. how many inodes will be allocated per unit of disk space (with `mke2fs` option `-i <bytes-per-inode>`, or indirectly via the `-T <usage-type>` option). Once the filesystem has been created, this parameter cannot be changed without destroying and recreating the filesystem.

That means, you won't be able to easily increase the amount of inodes in your filesystem, other than by extending the filesystem to gain more inodes as a side effect of the extension as the inode density is kept the same.

If the average size of files within the filesystem is lower than the `bytes-per-inode` value, then you'll be running out of inodes before you run out of actual disk space.

More modern filesystem types, like XFS, will actually generate new inodes on-demand, so this problem won't arise with them. With those filesystems, commands like `df -i` are likely to output dummy or nonsensical results.

Comment: wow! interesting information! I'll do some reading and then check if this solves it. thank you

Comment: great! so with your help I identified the problem and I tried to solve it by ... 1. moving all files out from `/home/` ... 2. applying `mkfs.xfs` to the `/dev/sda5` partition ... 3. adjusting `/etc/fstab` with the new UUID and xfs insted of ext4. ... and 4. moving all files back to `/home/` ... Now, my system boots, but I cannot log in! After entering my user and password and pressing return. I see a black screen that takes me back to the log-in screen... is there any other thing apart from `/etc/fstab/` that needs to be adjusted to the `xfs` instead of `ext4`? or what is now the problem?

Comment: Might be a file/directory permission issue, or a typo in your `/etc/fstab`. If you cannot login as root (even in text mode), then you can always use a Debian installation media to boot in rescue mode.

Comment: thank you for the support! Recovery-Mode is working and I used it to solve my issue. At the end I happened have my `/home/` under another `/home/` so I had my files in `/home/home/`. I moved all to `/home/` and deleted `/home/home/`. Logging in works now. (: